# QGIS rule-based symbology problem

Tags: qgis

In this project (using QGIS 3.18.1) the filter **"veg_actu1" = '600000' or "veg_actu1" = '601000' or "veg_actu1" = '601100' or "veg_actu1" = '602000' or "veg_actu1" = '603000'** does not work properly (white areas should be rendered)

[image]

If the filter is replaced by **regexp_match(veg_actu1, '(600000|601000|601100|602000|603000)')** or by
**case when "veg_actu1" in ('600000','601000','601100','602000','603000') then 1 end** it works fine. What am I missing?

Here is a link to the project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1slBl3b2Pd8yqDFqE4RW7L3bstAujg7dU/view?usp=sharing

If only this rule is on, display is correct.

[image]

Comment: the regex is not the same. It looks like the field is a string, not a number. If there is a trailing space (or any other character as a matter of fact), the equality will fail but not the regex, as the matching string does not have to be the entire string (`regexp_match(veg_actu1, '(6)')` will return 1 here). The `case when` is closer to the equality comparison though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to solve your problem, one involving other field-format and four avoiding the problematic `or` operator:

1. Use numbers, not strings - *the solution closest to what you have*
2. Use `like` functions - *the **easiest an most elegant** solution*
3. Use `case` condition - *the classic solution for such combined conditions*
4. Use `if` condition - *works, but a bit more complicated*
5. Use `in` operator -*tribute to @jdavid05's comment*

In detail:

1. Simply leave away the single quotes: as you don't have texts, but numbers, they are not necessary - thus not `"veg_actu1"='600000'`, but `"veg_actu1"=600000` :

   "veg_actu1" = 600000 or "veg_actu1" = 601000 or "veg_actu1" = 601100 or "veg_actu1" = 602000 or "veg_actu1" = 603000

[image]

2. function `like`, used with wildcards (underscores: `_`)

```
    "veg_actu1" like '60____'
```

3. `case`-condition:

```
    CASE 
    WHEN "veg_actu1" = '600000' then 1
    WHEN "veg_actu1" = '601000' then 1
    WHEN "veg_actu1" = '602000' then 1
    WHEN "veg_actu1" = '601100' then 1
    WHEN "veg_actu1" = '603000' then 1
    else 0
    end
```

4. `if`-condition:

```
if (
    "veg_actu1" = '601100',1,
        if (
            "veg_actu1" = '600000', 1,
                if (
                    "veg_actu1" = '601000', 1,
                        if (
                            "veg_actu1" = '602000', 1,
                                if ( 
                                    "veg_actu1" = '603000',1,0
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

5. `in`-operator (as proposed in the comment by user @jdavid05)

```
"veg_actu1" IN ('601100','600000','601000','602000','603000')
```

---

**Background**

After some testing, it turns out that the order of the original expression you used plays a role:

This expression returns styling for some, but not all polygons:

```
"veg_actu1" = '600000' or "veg_actu1" = '601000' or "veg_actu1" = '602000' or "veg_actu1" = '601100' or "veg_actu1" = '603000'
```

But with this expression, no polygon at all gets styled:

```
"veg_actu1" = '601100' or "veg_actu1" = '600000' or "veg_actu1" = '601000' or "veg_actu1" = '602000'  or "veg_actu1" = '603000'
```

I think the problem is linking several `or` opeartors one after the other. The help says:

> Operator OR: Returns 1 when condition a and b are true.

The examples in the help are like this:

- 4 = 2+2 OR 1 = 1 → 1
- 4 = 2+2 OR 1 = 2 → 1
- 4 = 2 OR 1 = 2 → 0

But you have not something like `A OR B`, but `A OR B OR C OR D OR E`. This seems to be problematic, at least when used with strings.

Comment: Yes, it works but it is a bit strange considering that veg_actu1 data type is QString. Also, if only this rule is checked (rest of styles unchecked) in the original project, the display is correct. Some kind of bug?

Comment: In fact, if the Expression String Builder is used, something like "veg_actu1" = '602000' is generated

Comment: Hm, strange, indeed. So we know **how** to avoid the problem, but not **why** it is a problem. However, if you use numbers, it's always good to format them so and not to have them in a string-format.

Comment: @Jorge Rosales see updated answer: the problem seems to be the `or` operator

Comment: You could also use the IN operator. ` "veg_actu1" IN ('601100','600000','601000','602000','603000') `

Comment: @Babel I agree with the format issue but in this case there are codes like 0111A0, 0121D0 or 0111E0.

Comment: @Babel as you have shown, there are several workarounds to solve the problem (you can also use regular expressions), but the "or" issue looks like a bug. You should be able to chain as many "or" operators as you need.

Answer (score 4):

There may be trailing or leading spaces - as @JGH pointed out. Try using this expression:

```
trim("veg_actu1") LIKE '600000' or trim("veg_actu1") LIKE '601000' or trim("veg_actu1") LIKE '601100' or trim("veg_actu1") LIKE '602000' or trim("veg_actu1") LIKE '603000'
```

and see if you get the proper results

Comment: Here is a link to the project ( https://drive.google.com/file/d/1slBl3b2Pd8yqDFqE4RW7L3bstAujg7dU/view?usp=sharing), it does not seem a trailing o leading spaces problem.